# Tablet will only double click after being plugged in a while

Tags: tablet

I have a Wacom Bamboo tablet and after a while of being plugged in, any tap will be seen as a double tap rather than a single tap. Restarting fixes the problem for a while but eventually comes back. What can i do to fix it? I'm using driver version 5.1.1 and windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is being plugged in? An external mouse?

The only solution I can think of quickly is deinstalling and then reinstalling the drivers

> Wacom implemented the following
>   changes and improvements in this
>   driver:  A problem in driver version
>   4.70 with double-click assist and erroneous double clicks was resolved.

I don't know what version and OS you have, so it's hard to pin-point what it could be

Comment: Did it work? Else I'll look further ;-)